# Ubuntu desktop 22.10 - Freeze 9 times on 10 on login

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

I don't want format and reinstall everything; I would solve my issue. I have a Ubuntu desktop 22.10 on a laptop Dell Vostro 3510 that, on login screen, when I type password, it freezes.
9 times on 10. After several try, i can finally login.
I reset bios on default values.
What can I check?

```
sineverba@notebook-vostro-3510:~$ uname -a
Linux notebook-vostro-3510 5.15.0-1048-realtime #54-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_RT Wed Sep 20 14:24:57 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
sineverba@notebook-vostro-3510:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-1048-realtime
```

Comment: Do you get a standard (non-realtime) bootable kernel ?

Comment: I don't know whar you mean, sorry...

Comment: Can you boot your machine under something else than 5.15.0-1048-realtime ?

Comment: OK, I don't know how I can use another kernel. I need to search documentation